# MongoDB - Changes to database while holding DBCursor in memory

Tags: java, mongodb

This should be a simple question but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I want to snapshot a collection by loading it into memory before changes are made to it. I then want to compare the snapshot with the newly updated collection.

My question is, if i load a DBCursor snapshot = table.find(); into memory and the database changes, will my snapshot reference be affected?

I'm basically asking if a DBCursor object holds all information in memory, or simply holds references to the collection.

Comment: Can you explain more about why you want to do the snapshot and comparison and how you'll compare the changes? You could do this with some kind ofcopy or snapshot of the data or by watching the oplog. I'd like to know more to make a better recommendation. A cursor returned from `.find()` is essentially a reference to the next document to be returned, so the results you have yet to iterate through can change as the database is updated.

Comment: I have a live feed of data entering my database that is using proprietary ingest code, which is doing a complete replace of the collection (hence why I want to snapshot). I want to process the data after the update based on what the differences are between the snapshot and the new data. I have a hook into the system before and after the ingest process. What if I just iterated through my cursor and loaded all of the DBObjects into a List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we do a find query, the cursor starts returning results from the beginning of the
collection and moves right. 
Your program grabs the first x documents and processes
them. When you save them back to the database, if a document does not have the
padding available to grow to its new size, it needs to be relocated.
Usually, a document will be relocated to the end of a collection, in this scenario you could get the same document twice (with different content but same id).

The solution to this problem is to snapshot your query. If you add the option, the query
will be run by traversing the "_id" index, which guarantees that you’ll only return each
document once.

```
db.collection.find().snapshot()
```

from the book "MongoDB The Definitive Guide"

Comment: Would it be better then, if perhaps I just iterated through the cursor and load all of the DBObjects into a List? Or are DBObjects bound by the same rules?

Comment: Yes, but if you using .snapshot(); find() in java will return you a cursor (java cusros = mongo cursor) and the problem could happen with the cursor. use find().snapshop() and turn it into a List (after the itteration has completed the cursor will be close and resources will be released)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the cursor and hold each document locally, but it'd be memory-intensive for large numbers of documents. You can retrieve the documents and store them back to another collection with something like

```
db.coll.find().forEach( function(doc){db.coll2.insert(doc)} )
```

This frees you from the memory overhead of holding the docs but you still have all the network I/O of pulling out and pushing back all the documents.

To put all the work on the server side, you could use [`db.collection.copyTo()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/) to make a temporary snapshot collection. Be sure to read the warnings though - it takes a global lock. This might be unacceptable in a production environment since it can block all other operations on the server.

A final option would be to use mongodump/mongorestore to make a dump of the collection and restore it to a different collection. This requires running other binaries, but if mongodump/mongorestore run local to the mongod it will be the fastest.